# Buefy timepicker does not clear input

Tags: vue.js, watch, timepicker, buefy

I have a project where I need to use [Buefy timepicker](https://buefy.org/documentation/timepicker/). There is an input which contains the value selected in the picker. Everything works well except the input element which I thing should be cleared if the model is set to null. The code looks like:

```
<b-field>
    <b-timepicker
        v-model="newTimeFrom"
        editable
        trap-focus
        icon="clock"
        :incrementMinutes="5"
        :placeholder="Set time from"
        class="mb-2"
    >
    </b-timepicker>
    <b-timepicker
        v-model="newTimeTo"
        editable
        trap-focus
        icon="clock"
        :incrementMinutes="5"
        :placeholder="Set time to"
        class="mb-2"
    >
    </b-timepicker>
</b-field>
```

and there are some watchers which should get the value from model variables and then set model variables to null.

```
data() {
    return {
        newTimeFrom: null,
        newTimeTo: null,
        times: [],
    };
},
watch: {
    newTimeFrom(newTimeFrom) {
        if( !this.newTimeTo ) return;
        this.times.push([newTimeFrom, this.newTimeTo]);
        this.newTimeFrom = this.newTimeTo = null;
    },
    newTimeTo(newTimeTo) {
        if( !this.newTimeFrom ) return;
        this.times.push([this.newTimeFrom, newTimeTo]);
        this.newTimeFrom = this.newTimeTo = null;
    }
},
```

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there is a timing issue. The value of the properties haven't been propagated to the `DOM`. Try `$nextTick()` which waits until after the next round of UI updates to execute the callback.

```
this.$nextTick(function() {  
  this.newTimeFrom = this.newTimeTo = null;
});
```

**Working Demo :**

```js
const example = {
    data() {
        return {
            minutesGranularity: 15,
            newTimeFrom: null,
            newTimeTo: null,
            times: []
        }
    },
    watch: {
      newTimeFrom(newTimeFrom) {
        if( !this.newTimeTo ) return;
        this.times.push([newTimeFrom, this.newTimeTo]);
        this.$nextTick(function() {  
          this.newTimeFrom = this.newTimeTo = null;
        });
      },
      newTimeTo(newTimeTo) {
        if( !this.newTimeFrom ) return;
        this.times.push([this.newTimeFrom, newTimeTo]);
        this.$nextTick(function() {
          this.newTimeFrom = this.newTimeTo = null;
        });
      }
    }
}

  const app = new Vue(example)
  app.$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/buefy.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/buefy.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.8.55/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"/>
<div id="app" class="container">
    
    <b-field label="Select timepicker">
        <b-timepicker
            placeholder="Click to select"
            icon="clock"
            :editable="true"
            :incrementMinutes="minutesGranularity"
            v-model="newTimeFrom"
            >
        </b-timepicker>
      <b-timepicker
            placeholder="Click to select"
            icon="clock"
            :incrementMinutes="minutesGranularity"
  v-model="newTimeTo"
            >
        </b-timepicker>
    </b-field>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you very much.